# Create csv file with metadata header followed by timeseries in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, metadata

I am trying to create a csv file that contains metadata in the first few rows, followed by timeseries data, so it can be processed by another web application. My csv file should look like this:

```
Code: ABC1

Frequency: Monthly

Description: Blah Blah

-------------------

2/1/1947    11.7

3/1/1947    11.9
```

I can create a csv file of the metadata:

```
metadata=pd.Series([('code: ABC123'),('freqency: monthly'),('description: describecode'),('--------')])

metadata.to_csv("metadata.csv",index=False)
```

I can create a csv of the timeseries

```
a=pd.Series((11.7,11.9),index=pd.date_range('1947-01-02','1947-01-03'))

a.to_csv("data.csv")
```

But I can't work out how to merge them together into the format at the top.

Comment: If you are using `pandas`, you should tag the question with it, otherwise everyone will assume this is about the `csv` module, or string manipulation

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> with open('test.csv', 'w') as fout:
...      fout.write('meta data\n:')
...      meta_data.to_csv(fout)
...      ts.to_csv(fout)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using DictWriter

```
toCSV = [] #put all your data in a list of Dictionaries such as {'Date': ... etc}
keys = ['Date', .... ] #list of keys for data
file = open( filename.csv, 'wb')
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(file, keys)
dict_writer.writer.writerow(Metadata)
dict_writer.writerows(toCSV)
file.close()
```

the keys create a number of columns and then the writer writes in your data (in dictionaries) according to the keys.