# Put Header and Dataframe into a new CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How would you define the header in CSV in Panda. Then after analyzing the data push it into a new file. How would you include the header into the new CSV file

Input:

```
John Apple <-- Header Start
9/21/2005
Duration: 00:00:06 <-- Header End

Time     Body_Temp Thermistor <-- Index
00:00:00 0.00
00:00:01 88.07
00:00:02 88.07
00:00:03 83.90
00:00:04 104.35
00:00:05 85.43
00:00:06 85.43
```

Output File:

```
John Apple <-- Header Start
9/21/2005
Duration: 00:00:06 <-- Header End

Time     Body_Temp Thermistor <-- Index
00:00:00 0.00
00:00:01 88.07
00:00:02 88.07
00:00:03 83.90
00:00:04 104.35 <--Points this is above 100
00:00:05 85.43
00:00:06 85.43
```

My Code so far:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = r'Alpha.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
uncommon = df.loc[(df['Temp'] >= 100)]
#can only figure out to find any temp above 100 and print it into a new CSV
uncommon.to_csv('Dummy.csv',sep='\t')
```

Comment: Related to part of your problem: [Create csv file with metadata header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168507/create-csv-file-with-metadata-header-followed-by-timeseries-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Just to be positive that method allows multiple write to the same CSV file without deleting the previous data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like this should work:

```
file = r'Alpha.csv'
meta = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=4, header=None)
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=4)
uncommon = df.loc[(df['Temp'] >= 100)]

with open('Dummy.csv', 'w') as out:
    meta.to_csv(out, index=False, header=False)
    uncommon.to_csv(out, sep='\t', index=False)
```

**Explanation**

- Read in your meta data into `meta` and actual data into `data` dataframes.
- Perform your manipulations on `data` and assign to `uncommon`.
- Write `meta` and `uncommon` separately to a csv file via Python's in-built `open` function.

**Alternative workflow**

But my preference would be to keep your data clean. Why not, for example, store a table separately with your metadata linking to filenames?

Your current method will prevent you from doing any meaningful analysis with the Metadata.

Comment: Well the first three lines wouldn't be the same so would this work? metadata=pd.Series([('Name: John Apple),('Date: 00/00/0000'),('Duration: 00:00:00')])

Comment: @jasonvan, perhaps. I've updated (but not tested yet).

Comment: I never worked with python or panda. So im very clueless can you elaborate your idea?

Comment: @jasonvan, sure I've updated. There are *many* resources for this, but I'd suggest the Python documentation as a starting point.

Comment: Program works needed to change the 4 to 3 since the 4th line is needed for the columns

Comment: Was wondering is their a way to break the data into sets of it meets a condition plot that set containing that value that met the condition ?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. I suggest you ask a separate question for this.